# THREE.js - shooting a ball with a curve ( X / Z axis)

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, physics

I'm new to THREE.js and with a very poor knowledge in physics but still I want to make a football manager game (played from top view) and I need to know that the kick of the ball is realistic as possible.

I was able to make the ball move and rotate in the correct direction while changing  the position of the movement when the ball hits its boundaries.

now I need to deal with a issue of the curve of the ball and how do I make it so the ball with move in an arc to the top and to the sides (X / Y) depending of the angle of the foot hitting the ball

lets just say, I need to know how to handle two scenarios:

- 1) when kick start from the near bottom axis of the ball
- 2) when kick start from the near right axis of the ball

your help is highly appropriated. Thank you!

**
- I've added a code showing what i have so far 
- I've added an image illustrating my goal (or this person scoring a goal)

[image]

```js
            /*
            *
            * SET UP MOTION PARAMS
            * 
            */

            var boundries = [40, 24] //indicate where the ball needs to move in mirror position
            var completeFieldDistance = boundries[0] * 2;
            var fullPower = 1.8; //the power needed to move the ball the enitre field in one kick
            var power = null; //will be set when the kick set in depending on the distance

            var isKickStop = false; //indicate the renderer weather to stop the kick
            var velocityX = null;
            var velocityY = null;

            //*** this is where i need help! *** 
            //how can I make the ball move in the Z axis with a nice curv up depending on a given angle
            var curv = 15;
            var peak = curv;
            var velocityZ = 0;

            var friction = 0.98;
            var gravity = 0.5;
            var bounciness = 0.8;
            var minVelocity = 0.035; //for when it need to stop the kick rendering
            var ballRadius = 3;
            var ballCircumference = Math.PI * ballRadius * 2;
            var ballVelocity = new THREE.Vector3();
            var ballRotationAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);

            //world meshes
            var ball = {};
            var field = {};

            /*
            *
            * THE KICK HANDLERS
            * 
            */

            function onKick(angleDeg, distance) {
                isKickStop = true;
                peak = curv; 
                power = (distance / completeFieldDistance) * fullPower;
                velocityX = Math.cos(angleDeg) * power;
                velocityY = Math.sin(angleDeg) * power;
                velocityZ = peak / (distance / 2);

                requestAnimationFrame(function (params) {
                    isKickStop = false;
                    animateKick();
                })
            }

            //** THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP - how do I make the ball move 
            // render the movements of the ball
            var animateKick = function (params) {
                if (isKickStop) { return; }

                ball.position.x += velocityX;
                ball.position.z += velocityZ;
                ball.position.y += velocityY;

                if (Math.abs(velocityX) < minVelocity && Math.abs(velocityY) < minVelocity) {
                    ball.position.z = ball.bottom;
                    isKickStop = true;
                    console.log("DONE!");
                    return;
                }

                if (ball.position.z >= peak) {
                    ball.position.z = peak;
                    velocityZ *= -1;
                }

                if (ball.position.z < ball.bottom) {
                    peak *= gravity;
                    velocityZ *= -1;
                    ball.position.z = ball.bottom;
                }

                // Figure out the rotation based on the velocity and radius of the ball...
                ballVelocity.set(velocityX, velocityY, 0);
                ballRotationAxis.set(0, 0, 1).cross(ballVelocity).normalize();
                var velocityMag = ballVelocity.length();
                var rotationAmount = velocityMag * (Math.PI * 2) / ballCircumference;
                ball.rotateOnWorldAxis(ballRotationAxis, rotationAmount);

                //reduce velocity due to friction
                velocityX *= friction;
                velocityY *= friction;

                //making sure ball is not outside of its boundries
                if (Math.abs(ball.position.x) > boundries[0]) {
                    velocityX *= -1;
                    ball.position.x = (ball.position.x < 0) ? boundries[0] * -1 : boundries[0];
                }

                if (Math.abs(ball.position.y) > boundries[1]) {
                    velocityY *= -1;
                    ball.position.y = (ball.position.y < 0) ? boundries[1] * -1 : boundries[1];
                }
            }

            window.onload = (function (params) {
                /*
                *
                * SET UP THE WORLD
                * 
                */                                     
                //set up the ratio
                var gWidth = window.innerWidth;
                var gHeight = window.innerHeight;
                var ratio = gWidth / gHeight;

                //set the scene
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xeaeaea);

                //set the camera
                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, ratio, 0.1, 1000);
                camera.position.z = 120;   
                //set the light
                var light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1);  
                light.castShadow = true;         
                light.position.set(0, 0, 35);
                scene.add(light);

                //  set the renderer 
                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

                //properties for casting shadow
                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; 

                renderer.setSize(gWidth, gHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);                   
                /*
                *
                * ADD MESH TO SCENE
                * 
                */

                // create and add the ball
                var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(ballRadius, 8, 8);
                //make a checkerboard texture for the ball...
                var canv = document.createElement('canvas')
                canv.width = canv.height = 256;
                var ctx = canv.getContext('2d')
                ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
                ctx.fillStyle = 'black';

                for (var y = 0; y < 16; y++)
                    for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++)
                        if ((x & 1) != (y & 1)) ctx.fillRect(x * 16, y * 16, 16, 16);
                var ballTex = new THREE.Texture(canv);
                ballTex.needsUpdate = true;

                var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    map: ballTex
                });
                ball = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

                ball.castShadow = true;
                ball.receiveShadow = false;
                ball.bottom = ballRadius / 2;
                scene.add(ball);
      
                // create and add the field
                var margin = 20;
                var fieldRatio = 105 / 68;
                var width = 90;
                var height = width / fieldRatio;
                var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 'green' });
                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, 1);
                field = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                field.receiveShadow = true;
                field.position.z = -1;
                scene.add(field);
                /*
                *
                * HANDLING EVENTS
                * 
                */
                var domEvents = new THREEx.DomEvents(camera, renderer.domElement);
                domEvents.addEventListener(field, 'click', function (e) {
                    //set points 1 and 2
                    var p1 = { x: e.intersect.point.x, y: e.intersect.point.y };
                    var p2 = { x: ball.position.x, y: ball.position.y };
                    var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p1.y - p2.y, p1.x - p2.x);
                    var a = p1.x - p2.x;
                    var b = p1.y - p2.y;
                    var distance = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
                    window.onKick(angleDeg, distance);
                }, false);  
                /*
                *
                * ANIMATION STEP
                * 
                */

                var render = function (params) {
                    //render kick if it is on the go 
                    if(!isKickStop){
                        animateKick();
                    }

                    //render the page
                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                    requestAnimationFrame(render);
                }
                render();
            })()
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.klika.co.il/scripts/three.events.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you know the angular and linear velocities of the ball, you can calculate the [**Magnus Force**](http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/211_fall2010.web.dir/Patrick_Brandon/what_is_the_magnus_effect.html) on it.

Comment: thank you @meowgoesthedog but, looks like its exactly the direction to go - but I still didnt get how translate this to a code

Comment: What do you mean? It should be as simple as calculating the force during the motion integration part (adding velocity to position) and applying it using Newton's second law F = ma.

Comment: Hi @RoeyZada, I don't understand how you calculate the angle, it seems you set the 2D Cartesian coordinate system and use the coordinate of the orthographic projection of the ball and click point position, as you know,  if we want the ball fly with a curve,  we can't hit the center of the ball, there must be an angle, and I think it's different form your angle. from my perspective opinion, it's not a good idea to show this with top view.

Comment: as I said @meowgoesthedog, my physics is kind of poor, so I cannot really get my head around what is F = ma, I have no idea what is F and what is ma

Comment: you are right @Craig.Li, and I can set the angle as a parameter. given I have put this as a parameter, how do I go from here?

Comment: So how did you come up with the above code if you don't know F=ma? Never mind. Calculate the force in `animateKick` according to the formula linked, divide it by the mass of the ball, and add it to the velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I build a model to mock this, the model accept several parameters, initial velocity and angular velocity, there are three force on the ball, gravity, air resistance force and Magnus force.

```js
v0_x = 0; //initial velocity
v0_y = 4;
v0_z = 1;
w_x = 0 * Math.PI; // initial angular velocity
w_y = 2 * Math.PI;
w_z = 0 * Math.PI;
m = 2; //weight
rho = 1.2; // air density
g = 9.8; // gravity 
f = 10; //frequency of the rotation of the ball
cl = 1.23; //horizontal tension coefficient
cd = 0.5; //air resistance coefficient
D = 0.22; // diameter of the ball
A = Math.PI * Math.pow((0.5 * D), 2); //cross-sectional area of the ball
t_step = 1 / 60;
b = (1 / 2) * cd * rho * A; //for convenience
c = cl * rho * Math.pow(D, 3) * f; // for convenience
vt_x = v0_x
vt_y = v0_y
vt_z = v0_z

animateKick = function() {
  if (ball.position.y < 0) {
    return;
  }
  tmp_1 = c * Math.pow(Math.pow(vt_x, 2) + Math.pow(vt_z, 2) + Math.pow(vt_y, 2), 2)

  tmp_2 = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(w_z * vt_y - w_y * vt_z, 2) + Math.pow(w_y * vt_x - w_x * vt_y, 2) + Math.pow(w_x * vt_z - w_z * vt_x, 2)))

  tmp = tmp_1 / tmp_2

  Fl_x = tmp * (w_z * vt_y - w_y * vt_z)

  Fl_z = tmp * (w_y * vt_x - w_x * vt_y)

  Fl_y = tmp * (w_x * vt_z - w_z * vt_y)

  //Motion differential equation
  a_x = -(b / m) * Math.sqrt((Math.pow(vt_z, 2) + Math.pow(vt_y, 2) + Math.pow(vt_x, 2))) * vt_x + (Fl_x / m)
  a_z = -(b / m) * Math.sqrt((Math.pow(vt_z, 2) + Math.pow(vt_y, 2) + Math.pow(vt_x, 2))) * vt_z + (Fl_z / m)
  a_y = -g - (b / m) * Math.sqrt((Math.pow(vt_z, 2) + Math.pow(vt_y, 2) + Math.pow(vt_x, 2))) * vt_y + (Fl_y / m)

  //use formula : s_t = s_0 + v_0 * t to update the position
  ball.position.x = ball.position.x + vt_x * t_step
  ball.position.z = ball.position.z + vt_z * t_step
  ball.position.y = ball.position.y + vt_y * t_step

  //use formula : v_t = a * t to update the velocity 
  vt_x = vt_x + a_x * t_step
  vt_z = vt_z + a_z * t_step
  vt_y = vt_y + a_y * t_step

}

window.onload = (function() {
  gWidth = window.innerWidth;
  gHeight = window.innerHeight;
  ratio = gWidth / gHeight;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xeaeaea);
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, ratio, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = -15;
  light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1);
  light.castShadow = true;
  light.position.set(0, 5, -10);
  scene.add(light);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

  //properties for casting shadow
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

  renderer.setSize(gWidth, gHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(D, 8, 8);
  //make a checkerboard texture for the ball...
  canv = document.createElement('canvas')
  canv.width = canv.height = 256;
  ctx = canv.getContext('2d')
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';

  for (y = 0; y < 16; y++)
    for (x = 0; x < 16; x++)
      if ((x & 1) != (y & 1)) ctx.fillRect(x * 16, y * 16, 16, 16);
  ballTex = new THREE.Texture(canv);
  ballTex.needsUpdate = true;

  material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: ballTex
  });
  ball = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  ball.castShadow = true;
  ball.receiveShadow = false;

  ball.bottom = D / 2;
  scene.add(ball);
  camera.lookAt(ball.position);

  plane_geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 100, 32);
  plane_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 'green',
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });
  ground_plane = new THREE.Mesh(plane_geometry, plane_material);
  ground_plane.rotation.x = 0.5 * Math.PI
  ground_plane.position.y = -1
  ground_plane.position.z = 20
  scene.add(ground_plane);

  render = function(params) {
    animateKick();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  };
  render();
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.klika.co.il/scripts/three.events.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>

</html>
```